# How to fetch the array data in this case?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the array data this way

```
function findnumberofaccourences() {
    var contact_names = [];
    contact_names.push('A');
    contact_names.push('B');
    return contact_names;
}

var result = findnumberofaccourences();

for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{
    alert(result[i].contact_names);
}
```

I tried this way , but i am getting undefined .

Could you please let me know how to achieve this

http://jsfiddle.net/13dLsag4/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the array items directly. It is invalid to access them through a property name because the array items are not objects

```js
function findnumberofaccourences() {
  var contact_names = [];
  contact_names.push('A');
  contact_names.push('B');
  return contact_names;
}

var result = findnumberofaccourences();

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  console.log(result[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put strings in your array.  Strings do not have an attribute named `contact_names`.

```
var result = findnumberofaccourences();

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  alert(result[i]);
}
```